# Maximum Capacity of Input Data (CSV or JSON format) in drawing D3 visualization?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I am trying to visualize a data using D3.js . The size of my data is 261 MB (No of rows- 400000 approx in CSV format). But I am not getting the visualization on browser even when i try to run with 100000 rows.
I am getting a WARNING:Unresponsive script ->A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js:1

However If i use sample data of about 1000 odd rows, I can see the output.

May I know what is the data limit when we try to visualize a dataset using D3?

Comment: It's more likely that it's not a d3 specific problem, but more an issue of javascript in general. What does your data structure look like?

Comment: My data structure is of CSV format with 400000 odd rows and I am planning to plot parallel coordinates graph using D3.js. http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281 is the link I have been referring to plot the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 does not place any limits on the amount of data you can load, process, or the number of elements you can display. All and any limits you encounter are specific to your particular browser and system.

In your case, you have far too much data to be displayed in a browser -- the load time of the CSV over the internet alone would be far too long. I would recommend either reducing the amount of data (very significantly) or pre-rendering visualisations that are delivered as images.

Comment: Seconding Lars's point, it's a good idea to save the SVG rendered by D3 and to use it as the basis for an image -- rather than screen capturing.